# Intellij: What does the green box around my source mean? How can I disable it?

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea

I enabled a setting by mistake in IntelliJ giving me a green outline around parts of my source:

[image: Green outline IntelliJ]

What does this outline mean and how can I disable it again?

Comment: did my answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your code's tab in `Editor -> Colors & Fonts`, and look for a setting with the following enabled:
[image]
Unchecking that box will disable the effect

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this happen when it is highlighting the current scope of an item.  It seems to happen when you hold down control and right click on a bit of code, but it probably depends on your keymappings.  (I'm using default GNOME keymappings)

Escape seems to clear it.